# Fatal error: 'mcheck.h' file not found

Tags: c, gcc, terminal

Ive got 2 header files and 2 c files in a folder. I am trying to compile the file which contains the main function. When I type gcc name_of_file.c in terminal I receive the following error

```
fatal error: 'mcheck.h' file not found
```

Please can somebody guide me.

Comment: Which platform? mcheck is a gnu header. It should be in /usr/include on linux but may need to be installed separately on windows (including cygwin or mingw).

Comment: Paul is leading you down the right path. You should provide more information. Also, the here's an online man page: [MCHECK(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mcheck.3.html).

Answer (score 2):

Are one of the header files `mcheck.h`? If so, how are you including the file in your code? It should be

`#include "mcheck.h"`

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to install mcheck?

On linux it might need a package, on windows you might have to download a zip.

Once you know where this header is on your system you can use

```
gcc -c -I<path_to_mcheck_dot_h> name_of_file.c -o name_of_file.o
```

NOTE: you can omit the -I command if the header location is on your PATH variable.

You may face more issues when it comes time to link your program, if it cannot find library that contains the functions declared in mcheck.h.